# How to force one bot.on runs before another bot.on

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I create a MS azure chatbot, and I using bot.on(.....);
Here is my sample code.

```
bot.on("event", function (event) {
    if (event.name === "greeting") {
        locale = event.value;
        console.log("event runs");
        eventTimestamp = event.timestamp;
    }
});

bot.on("conversationUpdate", function (message) {
 .............    
});
```

I want to make event runs before the conversationUpdate....Is there a way to do it in azure bot framework.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't because the Bot Framework Channel Connectors would need to route an actual `event` activity before it sends out a `conversationUpdate` type activity, which is sent when a conversation is initiated with the user. 

What you could do instead is not use the `conversationUpdate` type activity and instead only hook into `event` type activities. Can you provide more detail about your use case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recieve` middleware. It will run before `conversationUpdate`

```
bot.use({
    recieve: function(event, next){
        locale = event.textLocale; // you can use textLocale
        console.log("event runs");
        eventTimestamp = event.timestamp; // this event also provides timestamp
        next(); // don't forget to call next
    }
});
```